# Cant display images from GridFS, PyMongo

Tags: python, image, gridfs

**Hi all**, im a bit new in Python.
So I have a confused issue for me. I need to store image in database, and after that I have to display each image on client side. Im using Flask for rest request.

**So here I have my simpl marckup for submitind**

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="image">Select image</label>
    <input type="file" name='img' id='image'>
    <input type="submit" id='upload_img'>
</form>
```

**and here I get my request and save it to my DB**

```
@app.route("/upload", methods=["POST"])
def upload_image():
    # get current image file
    img_file = request.files['img']
    # get Content Type and File Name of current image
    content_type = img_file.content_type
    filename = img_file.filename

    # save to GridFS my image
    # fields <-- recive the id of just saved image
    fields = db.FS.put(img_file, content_type=content_type, filename=filename)
    # store the filename and _id to another database
    # so here we can much morea easaly get image from our GridFS
    db.Mongo['images'].insert({"filename": filename, "fields": fields})

    return index(images=[])
```

**My simple database model**

```
class db(object):
   URI = "mongodb://localhost:27017"
   Mongo = None
   FS = None

   @staticmethod
   def initialize():
       client = pymongo.MongoClient(db.URI)
       db.Mongo= client['gallery']
       db.FS = GridFS(Database.DATABASE)
```

And all saves is successfully.

**Retrive my image from DB and try to send it on clietn**

```
@app.route('/get_all_images')
   def get_image():
   images = db.Mongo['gallery'].find({})
   # try to get just a first image _id and fing it at GridFS files
   image = db.FS.get(images[0]["fields"])
   #send to the client
   return index(images=image.read())
```

**Here is markup for display image from the response**

```
    <div>
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{images}}" alt="">
        <div>{{images}}</div>
    </div>
```

and finnaly I get something like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPguH.jpg)

the response is look like this:
*b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00w\x00\x00\x00\x7f\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00\xd5j]\xe7\x00\x00\x00\x19tEXtSoftware\x00Adobe ImageReadyq\xc9e<\x00\x00\x03"iTXtXML:com.adobe.xmp\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00*

**The problam is** that I cant figute out how to convert this byte format into real image..and display it on a web page directly from database.

I try to make several variants to solve this problam..but in some how my mind is blow up..and I really dont undestand how to work with it.

Thanks for your time :)

IF somebady have any idias or advice how can I show images from database into client side...

Comment: I belive that this problam is very common...but I stick with this case just at the first

Answer (score 2):

I did it! :)

I figured out how to fix this by myself.

Actually the problem was in my response...and in some case on client side too.
Because when I send request from the server, I send the data in *byte* format,

```
 print(type(image.read()))
 <class 'bytes'>
```

while at the client I suggested the something like *binary string*

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{images}}" alt="">
```

There is my solution code:

```
import codecs
base64_data = codecs.encode(image.read(), 'base64')
image = base64_data.decode('utf-8')
```

And on the client I receive the string, which I paste into the `img` tag...and taddaaaa I got image from my database.

Thanks all who try to help me or figure out how to fix my issue.

I'm not sure that is the best practice, but it works.

P.S. sorry for my English :P